# Firebase Cloud Messaging: Notification Icon issues in Oreo

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I keep getting error `FirebaseMessaging: Adaptive icons cannot be used in notifications. Ignoring icon id` on Oreo phone. Instead of my custom icon I get default android droid image on green background. I definitely do not use an Adaptive Icon, I have created a new `svg` and transformed it into `png`, added it into `drawable` folder. The custom icon is displayed as expected in Android 5, but not in android 8 :( I tried to send the `"icon":"icon_name"` in the payload - no effect. I tried a smaller sizes (24px - 72px) - no effect. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: What version of firebase sdk are you using? Since version 12.0.0 they have solved a problem with notifications icon on android 8.0 https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#20180320

Comment: funny, i am using 15.0.0

Answer (score 0):

The issues was fixed by updating Firebase libraries and google play libraries to the latest ones. Make sure you check the [Google documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) because Firebase libraries do not have the same latest versions.

Comment: @DieterMeemken i had  to update all `com.google.android.gms` and `com.google.firebase` dependencies to the latest possible version. Then the icon issues were fixed automatically